# Set the log level programmatically using the Java Cassandra Client

Tags: java, cassandra

Using the Datastax Cassandra Java Client (3.2.0), is there a way of controlling the log level programmatically for the client logs?

Comment: cassandra sever log ? or client log ?

Comment: For the Client log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance:

```
        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        Logger rootLogger = loggerContext.getLogger("com.datastax.driver.core.Connection");
        rootLogger.setLevel(Level.TRACE);
```

Comment: Works fine importing the ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext